# Unity launcher and panel diappears when changing text colour in libreoffice

Tags: unity, libreoffice

We have quite a few laptops (about 200) where the Unity launcher and panel disappears when changing text color in Libreoffice (latest stable with ppa:libreoffice/ppa).
They all run 12.04 32 bits and Unity 2D and kernel 3.2 because of the poor support of Intel GMA3600 (binary cedartrail drivers)

So for a long time a thought the cause was the 2D and poor drivers.

Today I noticed the same behavior on a laptop with an Nvidia G72M (non-free drivers not installed) with the same LibreOffice, 12.04 32 bits and Unity 3D

This behavior is very trust worthy: It always happens. 
A workaround is press the power button and cancel: the launcher and top panel reappear.

So it's not the graphics adapter, it's not the 2D/3D, the LibreOffice version has changed already often on the laptops (but has always been a series 4). I have never seen the problem on my 64bit laptop.

I can't find related posts. Anyone else experiencing this or anyone having a sollution?

Answer (score 0):

Fix of this bug has been released.  Checkout this on  [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1024459).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and pointing out the bug. I don't know if it's exactly that (I'll check), but it looks similar behaviour. The bug is fixed in august 2012 in unity 6.2. A 12.04 Ubuntu runs unity 5.20. There is a duplicate bug for unity version 5 but it doesn't look like the patch is backported.